# Android/Apache HTTPGET Will not work, but in browser it does

Tags: java, android, rest, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple servlet running on tomcat. It implements a simple doGet() and works when I call it from a web browser like:

```
http://192.168.1.140:8080/Application/doTask?id=0&param=something
```

However, I'm trying to call it from an android application and I get nothing except a hang. I'm running it in an AsyncTask so it isn't really a hang, but I have this in "SendServerThread"

```
public SendServerThread(String state, int isHalfway) {
    mState = state;
    mIsHalfWay = mIsHalfWay;

    mRestClient = new RestClient();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String response = "";
    try {
        URI urlString = new URI(PI_ADDRESS + "/Application/API?id=0&setState=" + mState + "&percentage=" + mIsHalfWay);
        HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet();
        httpGetRequest.setURI(urlString);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);

        String line = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return response;
}
```

I verified the URL it's calling is correct, but I'm getting nothing. No response. I have INTERNET permission.

I call it like this from UI:

```
            new SendServerThread(state, isHalfWay)
            {
                @Override public void onPostExecute(String result)
                {
                    unlockUI();
                }
            }.execute("");
```

And it goes through with the HttpGet, but the thread never gets a response. If i head into the web browser on my phone I get the result. But from the app I get nothing - the thread hangs.

Any ideas are really appreciated, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: do two things and check...first remove the port no. 8080 ...and if it not worked...then use http://10.0.2.2 instead of http://192.168.1.140:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on airplane mode, then switched on WiFi so all mobile data was disabled, then it worked :(

Comment: You should have checked with a browser from your device too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing using the emulator, the IP address for localhost is `10.0.2.2`